# SNMP in context of SDN

Tags: snmp, sdn

SNMP is generally used to monitor the health of components in network.
For SDN [Software Defined network], is it desirable to use SNMP . I am having doubt like is it better to use some other protocol like NETCONFIG

Answer (score 0):

In general SNMP can be used for configuration of a device, however personally I will not stretch it too far specifically when network configuration operation  potentially spans across multiple devices and as a result will have higher order transaction requirements.

RFC3512 provides good perspective around configuration using SNMP. Reading through the RFC it will become apparent that within a device transaction relies on how well the MIBs (the objects used via SNMP for performing configuration changes) are designed and implemented. For configuration spanning across multiple devices the device transaction alone will not suffice, if rolling back the configuration is a requirement (this depending on the nature of service/use-case being addressed by your SDN controller). I would recommend reading the [Transaction Control in MIB Objects](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3512#page-14) further to understand the requirements on the protocol and eventually the capabilities of the MIB modules that one will be using for configuration.

Netconf was created with configuration of devices in mind and it offers various capabilities that are of use in this regard. These are covered in detail in the IETF standard for Netconf Protocol RFC under [Capabilities](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6241#page-51) section. The capabilities such as Candidate Configuration, Validate Configuration, Confirmed Commit, Rollback on Error and other such are specified in the standard which shall further aid in orchestration of a transaction across multiple device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So for SDN network how monitoring can be done?

Comment: It depends again on the capabilities of the devices in play in your network that you intend to monitor. A pragmatic approach will take you down a path where you'll have a mix of protocols (SNMP, netconf/restconf, CLI-parsing for operational and health data, netflow/sflow for packet capture and deeper analysis and some vendors provide features on the device to collect and post data to a configured location)